# JQuery UI Tabs choosing current tab with link and adding a class to a child element

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I need help with a function for jQuery UI Tabs. I currently am able to click on a link and open a specific tab. I want to add more to the function, basically still choosing the tab and then after the tab is selected, toggle or add a class to a child element inside the Tabbed Content. Below is the current function:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();//ID is the container of the tabs and tabbed content
 //creates linkable tabs for FAQ page   
    $('#showTab_faq4').click(function() {  //links to tab ID questions
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', '#questions');
        $("h3.toggle2").addClass("expanded");
    });
```

After the user clicks the link to bring up the tab "questions" I want a H3 tag inside the tab to have a class added to it called "expanded". The h3 has a class called "toggle2" to bind it to this function.

Any suggestions?